# wordprocessingml footnote number style (superscripts)

Tags: apache-poi, wordprocessingml, apache-poi-4

I just added a footnote to the word document.
but it seems little bit wierd.

Footnote numbers are usually entered as superscripts, but not now.

How can I insert a footnote number as a superscript?

this is my code..

```
r = p.createRun()
            String footnoteText = "exexexex "
            BigInteger footnoteId  = createFootnote(document, footnoteText)
            r = p.createRun()
            //r.getCTR().addNewRPr().addNewRStyle().setVal("FootnoteReference")
            r.getCTR().addNewFootnoteReference().setId(footnoteId)
```

Thanks!

[image: footnote number]

[image: footnote]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.python2.net/questions-332393.htm

```
XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles()
            XWPFStyle style = new XWPFStyle(CTStyle.Factory.newInstance(), styles)
            style.getCTStyle().setType(STStyleType.CHARACTER)
            style.getCTStyle().setStyleId("FootnoteReference")
            style.getCTStyle().addNewRPr().addNewVertAlign().setVal(STVerticalAlignRun.SUPERSCRIPT)
            styles.addStyle(style)
```